# Scratch Org: Digital Experience Home Page is Blank - Salesforce CMS Setup

Tags: scratch-org, digital-experience, salesforce-cms

I am having issues trying to setup Salesforce CMS within a scratch org. My `project-scratch-def.json`:

```json
{
  "orgName": "sfdx-org-name",
  "edition": "Developer",
  "country": "AU",
  "features": [
    "CMSUnlimitedUse",
    "Communities",
    "ContactsToMultipleAccounts",
    "EnableSetPasswordInApi",
    "Knowledge",
    "PersonAccounts",
    "PlatformCache",
    "ProcessBuilder"
  ],
  "settings": {
    "communitiesSettings": {
      "enableNetworksEnabled": true
    },
    "lightningExperienceSettings": {
      "enableS1DesktopEnabled": true
    },
    "securitySettings": {
      "sessionSettings": {
        "sessionTimeout": "TwelveHours"
      }
    },
    "mobileSettings": {
      "enableS1EncryptedStoragePref2": false
    }
  }
}
```

I have given the **System Administrator** Profile access to the CMS based tabs (Digital Experiences Home, CMS Channels, CMS Workspaces, and All Sites) as per the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.community_managed_content_start_using.htm&type=5) but still the Digital Experiences Home screen does not load.

[image]

I have tried loading this up in multiple browsers and still get the same issue. Is this not supported in scratch orgs?

Comment: what if you Search for Digital Experiences Home